# Routing in Drupal 8 for basic pages

Tags: routes, 8

I've just begun the transition process from D7 to D8.  I installed D8 and added a basic page w/ a menu link.  I then began to explore the new D8 routing system and expected to find a .yml file that contained information about where to find the added page but I don't see it. This is not a added module so it doesn't have a moduleName.routing.yml.

I'm looking for a conceptual description of why this does or doesn't follow the new .yml convention.

Comment: The routing system in drupal 8 (much like drupal 7) uses placeholders to describe dynamic routes. If you would look at node.routing.yml you would find the route that describes node pages.

Comment: @Eyal Probably not, it's an entity - those routes are defined elsewhere IIRC

Comment: Looks like they're in the [entity annotation itself](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8) @Eyal

Comment: Defining the links in the entity annotation does not create a routing object. Though it is possible to use a route subscriber and use the link templates.

Comment: @Eyal Any idea where they are in that case? They're not in node.routing.yml

Comment: @Clive see my answer below

Comment: Cheers @Eyal, must learn to read files all the way through...

Comment: Here is a very good in depth discussion on routing in Drupal - https://cipix.nl/understanding-drupal-8-part-3-routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node routes are declared using what is known as a [route provider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!RouteProvider.php/class/RouteProvider/8).
The node route provider class is [\Drupal\node\Entity\NodeRouteProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21NodeRouteProvider.php/class/NodeRouteProvider/8) and it is declared in the annotation of the node class:

```
/*
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "node",
 *   label = @Translation("Content"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Content type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     ...
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\node\Entity\NodeRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *     ...
 */
class Node extends ContentEntityBase implements NodeInterface {
//  ...
}
```